# Converting List<Map<K, V>> to Set<K> using Stream in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap, set

I have a list of map and try to convert it using the most proper way in Java 11. I tried something as shown below, but I think I should iterate list values using `stream()`. I use Java 11 and new features can also be used between Java 8 and 11.

```
public void demoMethod(final List<Map<Integer, String>> nameMapList) {
    // Tried but does not work
    List<Set<Integer>> nameIdSetList = 
        new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>(nameMapList);
    // What I want
    List<Set<Integer>> nameIdSetList = nameMapList.stream().// How to continue?
}
```

Example:
Input - nameMapList: `[{2=B, 1=A}, {3=C, 4=D}]`
Expected output - nameIdSetList: `[[2, 1], [3, 4]]`

So, what is the proper way to perform this conversion?

Comment: I did not down vote. But I have some questions. What is `itemTypeMapList()`? And if `ItemType` class does not matter, please replace it by some common class like `String` so others can easily try your code. Also it will be nice if you can give some example input and expected output.

Comment: Yes, I updated. Any help pls?

Comment: Converting a Map to a Set does't make that much sense. As a map has Key and value while a set only has values you are always going to lose information. What do you want the Set to contain? All Keys? All Values? Both?

Comment: @samabcde And of course any vote up so that question get attention?

Comment: I guess this is what you want.
    public void demoMethod(final List<Map<UUID, String>> itemTypeMapList) {
        List<Set<UUID>> itemTypeUuidSetList = itemTypeMapList.
                stream().map(map -> map.keySet()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Set should contain all the keys, not values.

Comment: @Henry upvotes don't get you attention, FYI

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Any suggestion?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Esta bien amigo.... You can still vote up ;)

Comment: `itemTypeMapList.stream().map(m ->m.keySet()).collect(Collectors.toSet());` is probably what you want

Comment: @samabcde Many thanks amigo. It seems to fix the problem and I think it is the most proper way.

Answer (score 0):

The only difficult part is the input is a List of Map, which is a bit confusing.
What I would do is to **compare the input and the output** to figure out the mapping first.

`List< Map<Integer, String> >`
`List<     Set<Integer>     >`

So the mapping is `Map<Integer, String>` -> `Set<Integer>`, which can be done by [`Map#keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#keySet()). Then remaining part is just some trivial googling with something like "java stream map" , which give us dozen of examples:
https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-map-examples/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-map-java-examples/
...

```java
public List<Set<Integer>> demoMethod(final List<Map<Integer, String>> nameMapList) {
    List<Set<Integer>> nameIdSetList = nameMapList.
            stream().map(map -> map.keySet()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return nameIdSetList;
}
```